# Visual Studio 2010 Prerequisites x64 installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

Installing Visual Studio 2010, **installation stops at Visual Studio 2010 Prerequisites x64**

I have:
Windows 7 Ultimate x64

I tried installing it manually and it also failed

The message says Setup Failed and the error log says:

```
[08/22/12,09:53:11] MSITOSIT: [2] CRootComponent::SetManager() - The Windows Installer package:
j:\vs_setup.msi
could not be opened.

Choose Retry to try again. Choose Cancel for exit setup.
[08/22/12,09:53:51] MSITOSIT: [2] CRootComponent::SetManager() - The Windows Installer package:
j:\vs_setup.msi
could not be opened.

Choose Retry to try again. Choose Cancel for exit setup.
[08/22/12,09:53:54] MSITOSIT: [2] CRootComponent::SetManager() - The Windows Installer package:
j:\vs_setup.msi
could not be opened.

Choose Retry to try again. Choose Cancel for exit setup.
[08/22/12,09:53:54] MSITOSIT: [2] CRootComponent::SetManager() - The Windows Installer package:
j:\vs_setup.msi
could not be opened.

Choose Retry to try again. Choose Cancel for exit setup.
[08/22/12,09:53:55] setup.exe: [2] ISetupModule::SetManager() failed in ISetupManager::LoadSetupObjectGuid() : vs_setup.dll
[08/22/12,09:53:55] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadSetupObjectname() - Failed in call to LoadSetupObjectGuid() for strName:  in file: vs_setup.dll
[08/22/12,09:53:55] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent(), LoadSetupObjectName failure: vs_setup.dll
[08/22/12,09:53:55] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent failed in ISetupManager::LoadComponentsFromDBObject(): vs_setup.dll
[08/22/12,09:53:55] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadDatabaseValues() - Failed in call to LoadComponentsFroMDBObjects()
[08/22/12,09:53:55] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Failed to Load Database Values
[08/22/12,09:53:56] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunLoadSetup() - Failed to Run the Intro
***EndOfSession***[08/22/12,10:00:25] MSITOSIT: [2] CRootComponent::SetManager() - The Windows Installer package:
j:\vs_setup.msi
could not be opened.

Choose Retry to try again. Choose Cancel for exit setup.
[08/22/12,10:00:28] setup.exe: [2] ISetupModule::SetManager() failed in ISetupManager::LoadSetupObjectGuid() : vs_setup.dll
[08/22/12,10:00:29] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadSetupObjectname() - Failed in call to LoadSetupObjectGuid() for strName:  in file: vs_setup.dll
[08/22/12,10:00:29] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent(), LoadSetupObjectName failure: vs_setup.dll
[08/22/12,10:00:29] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent failed in ISetupManager::LoadComponentsFromDBObject(): vs_setup.dll
[08/22/12,10:00:29] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadDatabaseValues() - Failed in call to LoadComponentsFroMDBObjects()
[08/22/12,10:00:29] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Failed to Load Database Values
[08/22/12,10:00:35] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunLoadSetup() - Failed to Run the Intro
***EndOfSession***[08/22/12,10:40:38] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64): [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64). MSI returned error code 1603
[08/22/12,10:40:40] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64) is not installed.
[08/22/12,10:40:40] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
.....
....
...
```

Comment: Looks like the installation media is corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the installer has read access to the drive J:.

I encountered a similar problem once, because my installer was on a drive where I had permissions, but the system account didn't.

Try moving vs_setup.msi to the C: drive.

Comment: This must be it, though I have another error now. I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070332/visual-studio-2010-prerequisites-x64-installation-error-code-1603