# Visual Studio 2010 Prerequisites x64 installation error code 1603

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

Installing Visual Studio 2010, installation stops at Visual Studio 2010 Prerequisites x64

I have: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

I tried installing it manually and it also failed

The message says Setup Failed and the error log says:

```
[08/22/12,12:31:29] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64): [2] Error: Installation failed for component Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64). MSI returned error code 1603
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64bit Prerequisites (x64) is not installed.
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[08/22/12,12:31:31] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight was not attempted to be installed.
.....
....
...
```

Comment: The erorr files are unhelpful and 1603 just means i failed there is no subtext. I would try and install the pre-req's manually you can find them here WCU\64bitPrereq\x64. You will need to have installed .net 4 before doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for many hours with the problem, I remembered having the same problem in the past. Both times the problem occurred because I had previously successfully installed Visual Studio 2010 (or Visual Studio 2010 Express) and in the meantime I have uninstalled it at the same PC where I try to install it now. This means that I get the problem with the installation when I uninstall it and try to install it again.

Then I saw an error 2908 in the installation log. I googled it and found this:

http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2007/11/12/windows-installer-error-2908/

The problem is that when I uninstall VS2010 some registry entries don't get cleared, so the installer thinks that these components are already installed. The man in the article above found this entry in the registry and deleted it. After that he was able to install VS2010 again.

Regarding my problem, I didn't find the problematic entry, so I had to reinstall Windows 7 from the beginning and then VS2010 installed successfully on my new OS.

Unfortunately the problem is not detectable in the same way for every PC so there is no specific solution. Anyway it has to do with Windows registry, so if anyone finds anything more, please add a comment to help others.

By the way I notice that many people have problems with VS2010 installation

Answer (score 2):

Error 1603 is a very generic installation error that sadly does not provide much information.

This might however **still** be permission-related.

[Microsoft's knowledge base](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/BV.aspx?ref=CSSKB&lo=SS&from=en&to=fr&a=http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834484/) provides the following possible causes regarding error 1603:

> You may receive this error message if any one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is encrypted.
> - The drive that contains the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is accessed as a substitute drive.
> - The SYSTEM account does not have Full Control permissions on the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to. You notice the error message because the Windows Installer service uses the SYSTEM account to install software.

[Another article](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/understanding-error-1603-fatal-error-during-installation) provides other possible fail reasons, and a walkthrough to repair this error.

Answer (score 0):

1. try installing VS_Prerequisites_x64_enu.msi in folder WCU \ 64bitPrereq \ x64
2. If error windows / symbols appear, create folder "symbols" in windows folder.
3. try installing VS_Prerequisites_x64_enu.msi again
4. Run the visual studio installer again after prerequisites has been successfully installed